# Determine if user is member of local group in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Below are my two best guess at finding out if our service account is a member of the `IIS_IUSRS` local group.

Neither will crash, however each `if` statment returns `false` each and every time. I've manually added/removed the user account to the group and verified that this is a "false" negative.

```
#Connect to Active Directory database using Powershell ADSI  adapter
#Keep this value as 'localhost' to ensure you connect to this computer
$cn = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost"
$env = "dev"
$monet = "s.Monet.$env"
$periscope = "s.PeriscopeWeb.$env"
$agentData = "s.AgentData.$env"

#add service accounts to IIS_IUSRS group
$iis_iusrs = [ADSI] "WinNT://localhost/IIS_IUSRS"

if (-not $iis_iusrs.memberOf | where { $_ -match $monet})
{
    $iis_iusrs.Add("WinNT://DOMAIN/$monet, user")
}    
if (-not (Get-ADUser $periscope -Properties memberof).memberof -like "CN=IIS_IUSRS*")
{
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
#Get the IIS_IUSRS group
$iis_iusrs = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/IIS_IUSRS"
$Members = @($iis_iusrs.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
#Populate the $MemberNames array with all the user ID's
$MemberNames = @()
$Members | ForEach-Object {$MemberNames += $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null);}

#See if your user ID is in there
if (-Not $MemberNames.Contains($monet)) {
    $iis_iusrs.Add("WinNT://DOMAIN/$monet, user")
}
```

Comment: You probably want to define $MemberNames as an empty array before trying to add things to it so that it doesn't become a string when it is assigned the first name, and you probably want to ! your If statement since you only want to add the user if it isn't already in the group I would think.

Comment: This totally works... however just curious if you know there's a more direct way than looping through the results (i.e. querying for one specific member)? Brand new to powershell, so still learning :)

Comment: As far as I know via ADSI this is the only way to do it. However I could be wrong.